# Understanding port numbers used by transport layer

Tags: networking

when I open multiple tabs in a browser, does the browser allocates different port number to each tab or not.

I'am using windows 7 64 bit OS, is there any way to check the port numbers that my browser tabs are using.

Right now I have opened two tabs, in one tab I'am viewing this page and in other tab I has opened a G-MAIL, does the two tab use same port ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser does not use ports for a its tabs, but to fetch the content of the tabs.

Depending on the content of a tab one or more ports are used on the machine running the browser. Those ports are allocated from the OS by the browser process or one of its threads.

After some time the content had been transfer to the client "into" the browser the ports are given back to the OS.

To see which ports are currently in use by an application run a `cmd` using adminstrative rights and issue

```
netstat -b
```

---

Assuming only one network interface a machine needs different ports for different connecions.

Comment: How to determine which port number does a web page tab is using

Comment: @Harish.N: This strongly depends on the browser used.

Comment: When I entered "netstat -b" command, I'am getting this "the requested operation requires an elevation".

Comment: @Harish.N: As I wrote in my answer, you need to "*...  run a cmd ...*" under an account having "*... adminstrative rights ...*".

Comment: Yes, I'am the only user of this computer. I entered "netstat -b" in command window and I got that message.

Comment: @Harish.N: Do `start->all programs>accessories` then **right**-click on `Command Prompt` selecting `Run as administrator`. Enter the correct password and you get a `cmd`-box with *elevated* rights.

Comment: OK, I got that one, now what does this foreign address indicates "a92-122-214-217:http"

Comment: @Harish.N: This are host names. Add `-n` to the call to `netstat` to have them resolved to ther ip-addresses. Use `netstat /help` for more help on this command.

Comment: Can you please explain what does that local address, foreign address and state represents.

Comment: @Harish.N: Under local address you find the ports you initially were asking for. The foreign address is where to connection goes to and the "State"-value tells you about the state of the connection. For details on the latter please go and read about TCP/IP connections and how they are setup, live on and finally are shutdown.

Comment: In some line, under label address I could see my IP address and in some line I could see some other address, what is that address ?

Comment: @Harish.N: Sry, but I cannot see what you see. What is "some other"? All addresses on the left und "local ..." are address of your machine.

Comment: sorry, these are the two different addresses I got                        101.233.216.149:51008 in one line , and in other line I got                    127.0.0.1:49159,                                                          101.233.216.149 is my IPV4 address, what is that 127.0.0.1 address that is appearing under local address

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the machine's internal loopback address. Every ip host shall have it. It's not connecting to the outside world. As it's for internal use only, it's the same on each host. However, as you really seem to be interested in this ip stuff go and get a book about it! Ok? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Every TCP connection should have a unique four-tuple `<SERVER IP ADDRESS , SERVER PORT , CLIENT IP ADDRESS , CLIENT PORT>`

In the case of a browser , if we open the same website (same `SERVER IP ADDRESS` and same `SERVER PORT`) in different tabs , then each tab will have different `CLIENT PORT` because `CLIENT IP ADDRESS` is same , until the TCP connection is open .

If we open different websites in different tabs , obviously it means we have different `SERVER IP ADDRESS` , `SERVER PORT` for each tab . In this case also , each tab will  different `CLIENT PORT` but same `CLIENT IP ADDRESS` until the TCP connection remains open .

After the TCP connection is closed , the `CLIENT PORT` is given back to the OS which can be later reused if OS wants.

Most browsers use HTTP pipelining which is a technique to keep the connection alive . for more [info](http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/119/)

You can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) trace and then check the source port for each packet you are requesting through the tabs in the browser . . It is a very good tool.

Comment: Means client uses random port number for each tab and that assigned port number cannot be assigned for other tab until previous tab has loaded or closed

Comment: Right now I have opened two tabs, in one tab I'am viewing this page and in other tab I has opened a G-MAIL, does the two tab use same port ?

Comment: It means that four-tuple for each TCP connection should be unique . Port numbers are assigned randomly by OS until the connection is alive .

Comment: both the tabs will have different port numbers if the connection for both tabs is open simulaneously. "You are viewing a page" does not mean that connection is still alive because HTTP is request-response protocol . Once the response is received completely , then the connection is closed . There are techniques to keep the connection alive like Websocket Protocol , pipelining

Comment: You mean once the web page is loaded completely that connection will not be alive and that port number could be given to another process

Comment: Could client assign any port number to a process, irrespective of whether that assigned port number belongs to well known or registered or dynamic port numbers.

Comment: Yes...but if there is there is any kind of activity in the webpage like advertisements , then the HTTP connection is open again , and then closed when the response is received .In  this case , the port number will not be same as previous connection.

Comment: CLIENT PORT is not in the control of the user , this can be done only by the OS.

Comment: How can I check the port numbers used by a web page tabs) in windows 7.

Comment: You can use Wireshark trace and then check the source port for each packet you are requesting through the tab .www.wireshark.org

Comment: That's a Good info, Thank you.

Comment: @Harish You can't. They might all be closed by the time you covet to run the command, and you can't unambiguously associate one port to one tab in the first place. Your question really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is based on a false assumption.

1. Port numbers are allocated to *sockets,* not tabs.
2. Sockets are created for connections.
3. Connections are allocated typically out of a connection pool for HTTP, for HTTP requests.
4. HTTP requests are created per page, and for all the resources referenced by a page: style sheets, scripts, images, embedded pages, etc.
5. Tabs are allocated to pages.

So you can see that the relationship between any given port and any given tab is practically non-existent. One connection, and therefore one port, may have been reused by several tabs. There is no necessary one-to-one mapping between them.